Lightningchart js, use different sampling rate in Medical Dashboard
I have ECG, Pulse rate, Respiratory Rate and NIBP to show in LightningChart JS Medical Dashboard which used a global sampling rate which is common to all channels [ecg,pulseRate,respRate,nibp]. But the sampling rate would change for each channel. ECG and Pulse Rate will have 256, and Respiratory rate will have 128.
I tried below but didn't work, as it now becomes 128 samples/second to all the channels.
Code:
const SAMPLE_RATE = 256;
const SAMPLE_RATE_NEW = 128;

Below is the function i used with my changes.
    let tSamplePos = window.performance.now();
    let tSamplePosNew = window.performance.now();
    let iSampleX = 0;

    const addData = () => {
      const tNow = window.performance.now();
      const seriesNewPoints = seriesList.map((_) => []);
      while (tNow > tSamplePos) {
        const x = tSamplePos;
        const xNew = tSamplePosNew;
        for (let i = 0; i < seriesList.length; i += 1) {
          const channel = channels[i];
          const dataSet = channel.dataSet;
          const sample = dataSet[iSampleX % dataSet.length];
           if (i !== 2) {
             // @ts-ignore
             seriesNewPoints[i].push({ x, y: sample });
           } else {
             // @ts-ignore
             seriesNewPoints[i].push({ xNew, y: sample });
           }
          // // @ts-ignore
          //seriesNewPoints[i].push({ x, y: sample });
          if (channel.name === "Electrocardiogram") {
            updateBpm(sample);
          }
        }
        tSamplePos += 1000 / SAMPLE_RATE;
        tSamplePosNew += 1000 / SAMPLE_RATE_NEW;

        iSampleX += 1;
      }
      seriesList.forEach((series, i) => series.add(seriesNewPoints[i]));
      channelIncomingDataPointsCount += seriesNewPoints[0].length;
      requestAnimationFrame(addData);

Setting the sampling rate:
    let channelIncomingDataPointsCount = 0;
let channelIncomingDataPointsLastUpdate = window.performance.now();
setInterval(() => {
  const tNow = window.performance.now();
  const chDataPointsPerSecond = Math.round(
    (channelIncomingDataPointsCount * 1000) /
      (tNow - channelIncomingDataPointsLastUpdate)
  );
  // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars
  const bpm = (beatsCount * 60 * 1000) / (tNow - tStart);

  uiList.forEach((ui, i) => {
    ui.labelSampleRate.setText(`${chDataPointsPerSecond} samples / second`);
  });
  channelIncomingDataPointsCount = 0;
  channelIncomingDataPointsLastUpdate = tNow;
}, 2000);

How do i get different sampling rates in different channel?
I am using this medical dashboard Online Medical Dashboard
Entire code is above.
I have tried multiple different solution but none of them worked. Need guidance on how to do it.
I tried using different sampling rate and push the data inside array, but i am not getting different sampling rates. Why I want this? The charts formed are different in different devices (laptop/desktop).

Since you are asking how to get different sample rates, I assume your data source doesn't include timestamps (X). Here's one way of achieving this:
The key here is preconfigured stream rate for each channel (128/256), which is supplied to PointLineAreaSet.appendSamples method as step parameter. Only incoming yValues are specified, leaving X coordinates filled in automatically.
As long as the incoming data matches the configuration (e.g. ECG indeed receives 2x as many Y values as "NIPB"), then this works wonderfully.
Zoom in to confirm that ECG & Pulse rate channels indeed have more data points than the other channels.


const {
    AxisScrollStrategies,
    AxisTickStrategies,
    emptyFill,
    emptyLine,
    lightningChart,
    Themes,
} = lcjs

const chart = lightningChart().ChartXY({ theme: Themes.light, defaultAxisX: { type: 'linear-highPrecision' } })
    .setTitle('')
    .setCursorMode('show-all-interpolated')
chart.axisX
    .setTickStrategy(AxisTickStrategies.Time)
    .setScrollStrategy(AxisScrollStrategies.progressive)
    .setDefaultInterval((state) => ({
        end: state.dataMax ?? 0,
        start: (state.dataMax ?? 0) - 10_000,
        stopAxisAfter: false,
    }))
chart.axisY.dispose()

const channels = [
    { name: 'ECG', rate: 256 },
    { name: 'Pulse rate', rate: 256 },
    { name: 'Resp rate', rate: 128 },
    { name: 'NIBP', rate: 128 },
].map((info, i) => {
    const axisY = chart.addAxisY({iStack: i})
        .setTitle(info.name)
        .setTitleRotation(0)
        .setChartInteractionZoomByWheel(false)
    const series = chart.addPointLineAreaSeries({ dataPattern: 'ProgressiveX', axisY })
        .setAreaFillStyle(emptyFill)
        .setStrokeStyle(stroke => stroke.setThickness(1))
        .setMaxSampleCount(100_000)
    return { ...info, axisY, series }
})

// Incoming data Y's only. X's automatically indexed according to known channel sample rate
const handleIncomingSamples = (allYs) => {
    channels.forEach((ch, i) => {
        const ys = allYs[i]
        ch.series.appendSamples({ yValues: ys, step: 1000 / ch.rate })
    })
}

// NOTE: This demo code WILL run out of sync (time axis will progress slower/faster than actual time)
// This is because `setInterval` may happen more or less frequently than requested.
setInterval(() => {
    const allYs = channels.map((ch) => {
        const sampleCount = ch.rate / 128
        return new Array(sampleCount).fill(0).map(_ => performance.now() % 1000 + 100 * Math.random())
    })
    handleIncomingSamples(allYs)
}, 1000/128)
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@lightningchart/lcjs@6.0.3/dist/lcjs.iife.js"></script>




As mentioned in the note, it will run out of sync, so if i use websocket to push the data into the array then and if i open the chart in 2 different devices then the charts will also be different, right? Bcoz of devices' performance (handling intervals).

Following to this code, if the websocket has stopped sending the data, then the chart would keep on showing up with old and repeated values, bcoz the array already has the data to show. When to clear this?

I am using lineSeries, and for some reason i dont have appendSamples method available for me, on add() method is available for me.

As seen when you open the chart, this example shows the time (x axis) as seconds since application start. This behavior by definition can't be out of sync between two different run times, as both have their own "application start" times. You'll have to be more specific how you expect the application to behave.

If this would be plugged to a websocket, and data would stop coming, then nothing would happen. The chart would stay still.

Please look at the code more closely. You are using "line series", the reference code is using "point line area series". Here's docs about the difference https://lightningchart.com/js-charts/docs/more-guides/beta-xy/
